# How to pass data-id to modal

Tags: php, jquery, html

I send an id from the database to the button. I can't send the id to modal inpıt. I tried so hard, but I couldn't.

Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="delete">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"><b>Deleting.</b></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="advert_delete.php">
                    <input type=""class="id" name="id">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <p>DELETE </p>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-flat pull-left" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-close"></i> Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-flat" name="delete_button"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete</button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Buton and Script:

```
 <button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm delete btn-flat'  data-id='".$row['id']."' ><i class='fa fa-trash'></i> Delete</button>


$(document).on('click', '.delete', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $("id").val(id);
    $('#delete').modal('show'); 
  });
```

Comment: If you want it on this element: `<input type=""class="id" name="id">`, you only miss the `.` to indicate a class as selector: `$(".id").val(id);`

Answer (score 1):

The following input field:

`<input class="id" name="id" id="id">`

Can be called in the following ways:

```
$(".id") // Calling *any* element with class="id"
$("input[name=id]") //Calling *any* _input_ element that has name="id"
$("#id") // Calling the element with id="id"
```

In your particular example, your field doesn't include the `id` attribute, so you cannot use `#id` as a reference (Unless you add the `id` attribute of course). But the other two methods should work.